# C# HttpWebRequest ignores set timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest

And just immediately throws a a WebException for a timeout.

HttpWebRequest.Timeout is set to 5000 (= 5 seconds).
But i get the exception after not even 1 second, what's going wrong there?

Also the default is supposedly 100 seconds, with the default the exception was still thrown immediately.

The exact message from the WebException:
The operation has timed out

Does this message mean something else?

following line throws this exception:

```
HttpWebResponse response = newRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Even weirder: It just worked for about half a year on at least 2 computers.

I failed to get in the bigger code in a readable fashion (lost the argument with the editor). But since it just worked before i have no clue what would be relevant anyways. The thing literally wasn't touched for months and just worked.

Comment: Can you please share the piece of code that generates the exception?

Comment: Server timeout?

Comment: What do you mean with server timeout? The problem seems to be that the programm doesn't actually wait and just throws a timeout. In my understanding you actually need to wait 5 seconds in order to get a timeout if the the timeout limit is set to 5 seconds. But what the program does: "Throw exception immediately upon reaching the line" it certainly didn't wait 5 and much less 100 seconds.

Comment: there is two timeouts from the client and from the server.
In you case you are setting client timeout. If you're response takes longer then 5 seconds than you will have a timeout.
There can be a server timeout. You have a client that has timeout value of 5 seconds, but server returns timeout in less than 5 seconds.
So I would suggest to ping the server then tracert the server host rout to check if there is a server side timeouts.

Comment: Okay, how would i check that? The address is usually reachable via browser. Alos ping doesn't show anything unusual. Traceroute also doesn't show any value above 100 ms. I still don't understand how it can immediately respond with timeout. But also only C# and also it worked before. Wouldn't server side errors return http responses? Or do you think a firewall refuses this specific request in an odd way? (And just recently started doing so.) Don't get me wrong. The provider in question actually did change something during the timespan in question. Still seems odd.

Comment: Okay, it's a problem with the other site all but confirmed. Just changed the address to one of my servers and i get through... Still i need to figure out why c# handles this like it does.

Comment: Are you using IP or Computer Name?  If you network is using DCHP then the IP address will get updated periodically.  You should in your code use the Computer Name.

Comment: All connections go through the internet.(Yes the one to "my server" too. It's located in france, and i am certainly not.) And the errors when connecting to the server of the other party are getting weirder and weirder. Almost certainly a weird network or firewall problem on their side. I am always using domain names and https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly a network/firewall problem specific to the other end of the connection.
Thus the sudden problem without changes to my side.

Connecting to other servers still works.

But the server in question causes somewhat random connection problems. So my guess is that the connection breaks at a somewhat random point from my applications point of view.

I contacted the admin and will report back if this gets confirmed.

Update:
Almost correct, forgot to answer.
The resolution was:
Support end to Win7

Now many might ask why is that "almost a firewall issue"?

Well, many admins removed the Win7 default TLS stuff from the whitelist, so their firewall started behaving "hostile" towards this type of request. Basically treating it like a garbage request.

The correct solution was changing to a supported windows version so .Net would default to a more widely supported standard.

In other words, yes, server timeout. Server sees non whitelisted request so apparently the acceptable response is not giving it any time whatsoever. Resulting in this seemingly inconsistent behavior with timeouts.